# How to display a date time in 16 Nov 2011 15:12 format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

I have a grid view column in which  I give the datefomat as dd MMM yyyy HH:mm and in code behind databound I change the time, the same time in database is not shown in the gridview, because of that the date is not displayed in `16 Nov 2011 15:12` format, it is displayed in `16/11/2011 15:12` format, how can i display it in `16 Nov 2011 15:12` format

asp

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SendDate"
  ItemStyle-Width="15%" 
  HeaderText="Sent At" 
  DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}"
  SortExpression="SendDate" />
```

c#

```
double timeDifference = Convert.ToDouble(Session["utimezone"].ToString());                    
e.Row.Cells[5].Text = Convert.ToString(senddate.AddMinutes(timeDifference * 60));
```

Comment: Is `SendDate` a `DateTime` field?

Comment: Yes it is, your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This format should work:

```
DataFormatString="{0:d MMM yyyy HH:mm}"
```

If it's not working, there could be something else going on. I would make sure that `SendDate` is a `DateTime` field, and also make sure that you don't have some logic overriding the `DataFormatString`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
double timeDifference = Convert.ToDouble(Session["utimezone"].ToString());                    
        e.Row.Cells[5].Text = 
        String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}",senddate.AddMinutes(timeDifference * 60));
```

It formats your date using the same FormatString you specified in your ASPX

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the [DataFormatString property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Comment: I have the  DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}"  in asp but it is not displayed in this format. because in row databound I make changes to the date from the db

Comment: I saw that afterward. I added some line breaks to make the `DateFormatString` more obvious, but the edit will need to be approved.

Answer (score 0):

you can chechk this msnd tutorial on how to handle custom dates and format [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)